# Squid Programming

Tags: squid

Does anybody know a good tutorial about Squid plug-in development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one in the squid documentation.  IIRC it's fairly straightforward - squid forks a process and passes data down a pipe to the process.  A somewhat out-of-date but still relevant programmer's guide can be found [Here](http://old.squid-cache.org/Doc/Prog-Guide/).

Answer (score 2):

Squid is nowadays a pretty modular and extensible platform, so it really depends on what you need to do. Most information can be found in the squid wiki (http://wiki.squid-cache.org)

There is the "helper" family of coprocesses-based extensions (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/AddonHelpers)

- redirector helpers (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors)
- authentication helpers for Basic/NTLM/Digest/Negotiate/Kerberos etc
- authorization helpers for LDAP/Active Directory/Session/...

In case you are interested in content modification there is ICAP for out-of-process adaptation and eCAP for in-process adaptation.

I'm sorry I can't post direct links; you'll find the data you need by looking for the relevant keywords in the squid wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find the [Add-On Helpers for Request Manipulation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/AddonHelpers?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryFeature%5Cb%29%7C%28faqlisted.yes%29) topic useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit  http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.4/cfgman/ to understand the squid completely...
I think the latest version 3.5 has arrived but this webpage can be a solution to your current problem.